# syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'

Tags: php

```
    <?php

            $rests = mysqli_query($connect, query:"SELECT * FROM `rests`");
        
        ?>
```

Не могу понять в чем проблема, делаю код по ролику с ютуба у парня работает у меня ошибку выдаёт.
Подскажите!!!

Comment: Не может оно у парня в видео работать, только если он свой язык написал, посмотрите внимательно =)

Comment: `query:` уберите, скорее всего это `IDE` подсветила параметр, а вы его вставили.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во втором параметре не нужно писать "**query:**". Об этом вам и говорит ошибка.

В итоге вместо:
`` $rests = mysqli_query($connect, query:"SELECT * FROM `rests`"); ``
Напишите:
`` $rests = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `rests`"); ``

И будет вам счастье.

Причина, почему у "парня с ютуба" так работает заключается в том, что некоторые IDE, например как *PhpStorm* подсказывают какие параметры должны передаваться внутри функций или методов.
В данном случае "**query:**" это как раз такая подсказка. И их конечно же не нужно переписывать.

Comment: Есть еще причина, "парень с ютуба" может использовать php 8.

Comment: Так и есть, "парень с ютуба" использует PhpStorm. Теперь работает ,спасибо!)

Comment: @Александр , рад помочь :)